# Will using one of the CustomActivityOnCrash libraries stop Firebase Crash from working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm thinking of using a library such as [this](https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash) one, however I am worried that FirebaseCrash will stop loading as the library probably overrides the method that is called on crash.

Will Firebase Bug Reports/Firebase Crash stop working if I use a library like [this](https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash)?

Comment: This library is independent from firebase crash, I dont think it will cause anything to firebase. In CustomActivityOnCrash library in point no2: follow the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of that library. Versions up to 1.5.0 cause Firebase Crash Reporting to stop working. The app will not crash, but the original `UncaughtExceptionHandler` set internally by Firebase will never be invoked, so you will get no crash data in your Firebase console.

Version 2.0.0 of the library fixes this issue and everything works as normal.

Update your dependency to make it work as expected:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the library's documentation](https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash#2-set-up-your-application):

> WARNING! If you already have ACRA, Crashlytics or any similar library in your app, it will still work as normal, but the CustomActivityOnCrash initialization MUST be done first, or the original reporting tool will stop working.

It will still work fine.

Comment: Missed that. Thanks